# Как доработать генератор разбиения строки

Tags: php

Проблема в том, что надо создавать комбинацию М/K/id работает криво, если число меньше 1 000 000 то     1М, и тд...

```
 <?
    $gg = "999";
    if($gg <= "1000000"){
    $ff = "1M";
    if($gg <= "1000"){
    $yu = "1K";
    }elseif($gg > "1000"){
    $ro = mb_substr($gg,'1');
    $ty = ($ro / 1000);
    $yu = ceil($ty)."K";
    }
    }elseif($gg>"1000000"){
    $ty = ($gg / 1000000);
    $ff = ceil($ty)."M";
    if($gg <= "1000"){
    $yu = "1K";
    }elseif($gg > "1000"){
    $ro = mb_substr($gg,'1');
    $ty = ($ro / 1000);
    $yu = ceil($ty)."K";
    }
    }
    echo $ff."/".$yu."/id".$gg;?>
```

Comment: Нет, тут другое, необходимо получить несколько параметров из 1 числа, ибо это будет являться путём к папке юзера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так?

```
$number = '1234567'; // Число
$NM = 0;
$NK = 0;

if ($number >= 1000000) {
    $NM = intval($number / 1000000);
    $number = ($number % 1000000);
}
if ($number >= 1000) {
    $NK = intval($number / 1000);
}

var_dump($NM . 'M/' . $NK . 'K/' . $number);
```

Comment: Спасибо, пойдёт))(  вообще хрен с ним как будет выглядеть ответ...ибо это будет под создание путей (папок юзера)_)

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев Если хотите под папки, посмотрите в сторону `md5`, кидаем число в `md5` получаем хэш, например `qwerty` (ну я для примера, там будет больше символов), и потом можно например по первым 4 буквам и разбивать на папки: `/qw/er/ваш файл`